# Bootstrap css content doesnt expand / scroll

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a form in bootstrap, but as the content expands beyond the screen, the screen doesnt show the scroll control, so i cant see or reach the extra content?!

I've tried setting overflow but it's as if there is no extra content?

To see a live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8hYVq/

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Majstorce</title>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">



        <script type="text/javascript" src="/admin/jsi18n/"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/core.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.init.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.__admin_media_prefix__ = "/static/admin/";
        </script>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/calendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js"></script>



 </head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
 <div class="navbar-inner">
  <div class="container">
  <h1>My test page...</h1>

    <ul class="nav">
     <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>

    </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="container">

<h3>My form</h3>
<div class="row">
  <div class="span8">
    <form action="" method="POST">

            <div style='display:none'><input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='7ea0a3a7726d12e63e4fee21a7d53f21' /></div>
            <p><label for="Title">Title:</label> <input id="title" type="text" name="title" maxlength="255" /></p>
<p><label for="Category">Category:</label> <select name="Category" id="Category">
<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
<option value="1">Cars</option>
<option value="2">Food</option>
</select></p>
<p><label for="Description">Description:</label> <input id="Description" type="text" name="Description" maxlength="255" /></p>

<p><label for="user">User:</label> <select name="user" id="user">
<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
<option value="1">CustomUser object</option>
</select></p>
<p><label for="id_grad">Location:</label> <select name="Location" id="Location">
<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
<option value="1">New York</option>
<option value="2">Washington</option>

</select></p>
<p><label for="From">From:</label> <input id="From" type="text" class="vDateField" name="From" size="10" /></p>
<p><label for="To">To:</label> <input id="To" type="text" class="vDateField" name="To" size="10" /></p>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post"/>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="span4">asd</div>
  <div class="clear" style="clear:both">&nbsp;</div>

</div>

 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put the `.container` outside the `.navbar`.

Comment: Oh god thank you such a good eye!

Comment: You are welcome. Another good way to thank someone is to go to his profile, find other questions this person answered and vote for good ones.

Answer (score 0):

As Pavlo Mykhalov hawk eye noticed, the container was part of the navbar class, and hence the error... 
Thank you Pavlo!